# Adding a new column that the values are determined by another column (after groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[This is the original dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXRsM.png)
, and I want to add a new column called [withdraw_#], which recorded how many times the parent_user_id withdraw their money [I don't know the steps after I groupby('parent_user_id')]

[This is the revised dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5A3.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
df['WITHDRAW_#']='' 
df['WITHDRAW_#']=df.groupby(['user','side']).transform('count').fillna(0)
df['WITHDRAW_#']=df['WITHDRAW_#'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
    user      side amount
0  10067  WITHDRAW   2000
1  10057   DEPOSIT   5000
2  10067  WITHDRAW   1000
3  10057  WITHDRAW   6000
```

Output:

```
    user      side amount  WITHDRAW_#
0  10067  WITHDRAW   2000           2
1  10057   DEPOSIT   5000           1
2  10067  WITHDRAW   1000           2
3  10057  WITHDRAW   6000           1
```

Comment: Hi manjari, thanks for your reply, but I thought the answer is different from what I want.

Comment: @jackmark I thought your expectation is to get the each user count who have withdrew some amount. Could you please specify your requirement

Comment: OP wants the DEPOSIT row to also show count of 1

Comment: @jackmark edited answer for the same

Comment: @manjari I got the error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: @jackmark can you share the logic you are trying.. The above logic is working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(x):
    return sum(x=="WITHDRAW")
df["withdraw_#"] = df.groupby("user_id")["side"].agg(fun)
```

or

```
df["withdraw_#"] = df.groupby("user_id")["side"].agg(lambda x: sum(x=="WITHDRAW"))
```